# awk: select lines begining with string and ending with string

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I have input.txt

```
abcd
abcg
```

To select lines beginning with 'a' and ending with 'g' I write:

```
cat input.txt | awk '/^a/' | awk '/g$/{print $0}'
```

How can I combine the regular expressions `^a` and `g$` to be able to use only one instance of `awk`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't ^s$ in regex match a string like "starts with s and ends with s"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613519/why-doesnt-s-in-regex-match-a-string-like-starts-with-s-and-ends-with-s) While the problem is not exactly the same, the answer should still apply to yours.

Comment: @AdminBee, no it doesn't answer my question. My question is more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a single regex that matches both start and finish:

```
awk '/^a.*g$/' input.txt
```

Or, if you really want to use two, you can combine them with `&&`:

```
awk '/^a/ && /g$/' input.txt
```

Comment: Is `.*` a combination of `.` and `*` or is it a separate operator?

Comment: It is a combination of `.` (any character) and the modifier `*` which means "0 or more times", so it means "match absolutely anything, including nothing at all".

Comment: Note that *anything* is not the same thing as *any sequence of characters*. For instance, in a UTF-8 locale and on a GNU system, both don't give the same outcome on the output of `printf 'appliqu\351ing\n'` (appliquéing encoded in ISO8859-1) for instance.

Comment: Sigh. I will never understand this sort of thing. You're absolutely right, @StéphaneChazelas, `printf 'appliqu\351ing\n' | awk '/^a.*g$/'` returns nothing while `printf 'appliqu\351ing\n' | awk '/^a/ && /g$/'` works on my Arch system, although at least `printf 'appliqu\351ing\n' | perl -ne 'print if /^a.*g$/'` and `printf 'appliqu\351ing\n' | perl -ne 'print if /^a/ && /g$/'` both work. I take it that `.` doesn't match  `\351` for some reason?

Comment: `\351` cannot be decoded into a character in UTF-8, so it's not matched by `.`. With `perl`, you need `-C` or `-Mopen=locale` to decode input as text.

Comment: The real question should be: Why are lines with invalid character allowed in your text file ? @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Any of `-C0` or `-C` or `-C127` or `-Mopen=locale` will match *appliquéing encoded in ISO8859-1* using `.*`. So, it will get printed. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: On my system, with perl 5.36.0, `printf 'appliqu\351ing\n' | perl -ne 'print if /^a.*g$/'` is printed, with no extra options.

Comment: But that's not decoded as text, so it's only valid in single-byte locales and only because your pattern has no non-ASCII characters. For instance `perl -ne 'print if /^..$/'` would print a line containing `ê` in a locale using UTF-8. With `-C`/`-Mopen=locale`, @QuartzCristal with `-w`, you'd get errors on that `\351` bytes, and without it with `-Mopen=locale` would be decoded into something like the 4 character `\xE9` string. In any case POSIXly, the behaviour of awk/grep on non-text is unspecified. I was just pointing out that the two approaches were not strictly equivalent.

Comment: Also beware there are some locales where the charset has characters whose multibyte encoding ends in the same encoding as that of `g`, so `printf 'appliqu\351ing\n' | perl -ne 'print if /^a.*g$/'` could match on lines that end in those characters.

Answer (score 2):

No need for awk, just grep:

```
grep "^a.*g$" input.txt
```

Comment: Or `grep -x 'a.*g'`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas A grep command won't match *appliquéing encoded in ISO8859-1*.

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer as generic as possible using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), here is an alternate way to perform the desired action, where [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) string is passed as [variable](/questions/tagged/variable) from the command line.

Demonstration test data is embedded in this example.

Using the script

```
#!/bin/sh

sSTRT="${1}"
sEND="${2}"

echo "John Wells
John Wayne
Robert Wayne" |
awk -v sTrt="^${sSTRT}" -v sEnd="${sEND}\$" ' $0 ~ sTrt && $0 ~ sEnd '
```

and executing the command

```
script "John" "Wayne"
```

the output is

```
John Wayne
```

with other lines ignored.

Special note: the "^" abd "$" must be passed literally as part of the awk variables.